# Maximum of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization

Let $0 \leq x,y,z \leq 1.$ Define the function
 $$f(x,y,z) = y^2 -2z^2 + 2x^2y. $$
What is the maximum of $f$ subject to the equality constraint
  $$ x = z + y\sqrt{(1-y^2)}?$$
Numerical methods give that the answer is around $1.87$ Could you give me a hint?

Comment: Maybe you could use Lagrange multipliers? And then if necessary check at the boundaries.

Comment: The answer to this problem (the maximum of $f$ subject to this condition) can be expressed in algebraic numbers only (as a root of a polynomial of order 8). Are you sure there is no typo? Try `Maximize[{y^2 - 2 z^2 + 2 x^2 y, 0 <= x <= 1 && 0 <= y <= 1 && 0 <= z <= 1 &&  x == z + y Sqrt[1 - y^2]}, {x, y, z}, Reals] // FullSimplify` if you have access to _Mathematica_.

Comment: @Sasha - that actually gives $x=1$ (though $f \approx 1.87$)